# List of all UK political party/politician facebook pages

Tags: data-request, uk, social-media, elections, politics

I'm working on a Chrome extension to analyse Facebook advert targetting by political parties, in the run-up to the 2017 UK general election. (https://whotargets.me)

In order to conduct our analysis, we need to match adverts to political parties.

Do you know any lists of UK political party / politician facebook pages? Ideally we need:

- page ID
- vanity URL string
- page name
- party affiliation

We're really eager to find regional/local/branch party and politician pages.

Answer (score 4):

You can start with http://everypolitician.org, here's a [link to the UK data](https://github.com/everypolitician/everypolitician-data/tree/master/data/UK/Commons) on github.

At [Unigraph](http://unigraph.io) we've merged everypolitician's with data from Wikidata and Freebase, so you can conveniently query it, for example "[get the facebook,  twitter and wikidata ids of Adam Holloway, the fb and twitter urls and the party he is member of](http://try.unigraph.rocks/?q=%7B%0A%20%20subjects(property%3A%20%22label%22%2C%20text%3A%20%22Adam%20Holloway%22%2C%20lang%3A%20en)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20uid%0A%20%20%20%20wikidata_id%20%40propagate%0A%20%20%20%20twitter_username_id%0A%20%20%20%20facebook_id%0A%20%20%20%20url(filter%3A%20%22%24url%20%3D~%20%60.*twitter.*%7C.*facebook.*%60%22)%0A%20%20%20%20political_party_member%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20label.en%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20wikidata_id%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20uid%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)".

Reach to me for an API key and any questions you might have on how to best extract the data you'll need.

Answer (score 3):

Wikidata: about 500 UK politicians on Facebook.

```
SELECT ?politician ?politicianLabel ?url ?partyLabel WHERE {
    ?politician wdt:P2013 ?facebook .
    ?politician wdt:P27 wd:Q145 .
    ?politician wdt:P106 wd:Q82955 .
    OPTIONAL {?politician wdt:P102 ?party}
    BIND (IRI(CONCAT('https://facebook.com/', ?facebook)) AS ?url)  
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
} ORDER BY (bound(?party))
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fpolitician%20%3FpoliticianLabel%20%3Furl%20%3FpartyLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fpolitician%20wdt%3AP2013%20%3Ffacebook%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fpolitician%20wdt%3AP27%20wd%3AQ145%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fpolitician%20wdt%3AP106%20wd%3AQ82955%20.%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fpolitician%20wdt%3AP102%20%3Fparty%7D%0A%20%20%20%20BIND%20(IRI(CONCAT(%27https%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com%2F%27%2C%20%3Ffacebook))%20AS%20%3Furl)%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20(bound(%3Fparty)))